# Is this space homeomorphic to $\Bbb{T}^4$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ be the quotient space of $\Bbb{R}^4$ defined by the equivalence relation

$(w_1, x_1, y_1, z_1) \sim (w_2, x_2, y_2, z_2)$ iff $w_1 - w_2$, $x_1 - x_2$, $y_1 - y_2$, and $z_1 - z_2$ are all integers, and their sum is even (that is, $w_1 - w_2 + x_1 - x_2 + y_1 - y_2 + z_1 - z_2$ is even). (This is equivalent to matching up all pairs of opposite cells in a regular 24-cell, oriented the same way).

Is this homeomorphic to $\Bbb{T}^4$ (or to any well-known topological space)?

Comment: Yes, of course: The space is the quotient of $R^4$ by an index 2 subgroup $G$ in $Z^4$, hence, $G$ itself is conjugate to $Z^4$ by a linear transformation.